# GraphQL conditiontal Filter

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphcool

Using a GraphCool backend, is there a way to have conditional filter in a query?

let's say I have a query like this:

```
query ($first: Int, $skip: Int, $favorited: Boolean) {
  allPhotos (
    first: $first
    skip: $skip
    filter: {
      favorited: $favorited
    }
  )
  {
    id
    url
    title
    favorited
  }
}

//variables: { "first": 10, "skip", "favorited": true }
```

The query above would either:

1) Fetch only photos that are favorited.

2) Fetch only photos that are not favorited.

My problem is I want to be able to either:

1) query photos that are ONLY either favorited OR not favorited.

2) query photos regardless of whether or not they're favorited.

How do I conditionally include filters? Can I? I'm doing something with react-apollo in Javascript and I could figure out a solution with code, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it in graphql land.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GraphQL variables don't necessarily have to be scalars -- they can be input types as well. So your query could look like this:

```
query ($first: Int, $skip: Int, $filter: PhotoFilter) {
  allPhotos (
    first: $first
    skip: $skip
    filter: $filter
  )
  {
    #requested fields
  }
}
```

The variables you pass along with your query will now include an Object (i.e. `{ favorited: true }`) for `filter` instead of a boolean for `favorited`.

To cover all three of your scenarios, send either:

1. `{ favorited: true }`
2. `{ favorited: false }`
3. `{}` (no filters)

Edit: I *think* the name of the input type in this case would be `PhotoFilter` but you may want to double check your schema to be sure.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know variables did not have to be scalars! I had a hack in javascript where I would make the favorited variable be undefined (not null) and it would behave the way I want it to. I think if a variable is undefined then it is simply ignored. This is much better. I'm using GraphqlCool so this is quite easy. I just have to give the $photoFilter the type of PhotoFIlter.